# Open url is a specific Tab using default browser

Tags: vb.net, url, browser, browser-tab

How do I open a url in VB.NET 2017, using the default browser and in a specific tab ?

The tab will have specific words in it, so I can reference is that way.

Is this possible ??

Comment: Yes it is possible, but too broad here. How do I know, I have done it ... One hint is automation...

Comment: OK so how - Im using -  Process.Start(url), to open the URL i need using the default browser, but how would I target a specific tab ??

Comment: you want to create an app and create your own tab and each tab open a web site?

Comment: I want to have an app, (hidden, responds to keyboard shortcuts - done), when a key combo appears - then open a tab in the default browser (chrome or firefox or ie), seperate from app,  in a perfect world then it would close all tabs that use a specific domain

Comment: OK so how is it done ????, i can currently open a new tab which is done be default with Process.Start(url), but i want to overwrute a tab that is using a certain domain - can this be done